# Storing zeros after float division

Tags: python-3.x

```
#!/bin/python3

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys

# Complete the plusMinus function below.
def plusMinus(arr):
    p=0
    m=0
    z=0
    for i in arr:
        if i>0:
            p+=1
        elif i<0:
            m+=1
        else:
            z+=1
    a=[round((p/len(arr)),6),round((m/len(arr)),6),round((z/len(arr)),6)]
    print (a)
    return a

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())

    arr = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

    plusMinus(arr)
```

I was just practicing some challenges in hackerrank. Then the result expected was 0.350000 but it gives 0.35 ( the precision was 6 ). How do i do this?

Answer (score 0):

specify precision in the print statement:

```
print("{:0.6f}".format(a))
```

As @ashgetstazered's points out in comments, formatted strings are more readable (available in python >=3.6)

```
print(f"{a:.6f}")
```

Comment: or `print(f"{a:.6f}")` if you're using 3.6 or above. As well as looking nicer they're faster too! :)